# Can't save attributes product values in backend?

Tags: magento, attributes

I have a function that programatically creates for me attributes like following:

```
     function createAttribute($code, $label, $attribute_type, $product_type,$attributeSetId)
    {
    $_attribute_data = array(
    'attribute_code' => $code,
    'is_global' => '1',
    'frontend_input' => $attribute_type, 
    'default_value_text' => '',
    'default_value_yesno' => '0',
    'default_value_date' => '',
    'default_value_textarea' => '',
    'is_unique' => '0',
    'is_required' => '0',
    'apply_to' => array($product_type), 
    'is_configurable' => '0',
    'is_searchable' => '0',
    'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '0',
    'is_comparable' => '0',
    'is_used_for_price_rules' => '0',
    'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => '0',
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => '1',
    'is_visible_on_front' => '1',
    'used_in_product_listing' => '0',
    'used_for_sort_by' => '0',
    'is_filterable' => '1',
    'frontend_label' => $label,

);
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
if (!isset($_attribute_data['is_configurable'])) {
    $_attribute_data['is_configurable'] = 0;
}
if (!isset($_attribute_data['is_filterable'])) {
    $_attribute_data['is_filterable'] = 0;
}
if (!isset($_attribute_data['is_filterable_in_search'])) {
    $_attribute_data['is_filterable_in_search'] = 0;
}
if (is_null($model->getIsUserDefined()) || $model->getIsUserDefined() != 0) {
    $_attribute_data['backend_type'] = $model->getBackendTypeByInput($_attribute_data['frontend_input']);
}


$model2=Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup','core_setup');
$attributeGroupId = '';
if($attributeSetId)
{
     $attributeGroup=$model2->getAttributeGroup('catalog_product',$attributeSetId,'Noutati');

if(array_key_exists('attribute_group_id',$attributeGroup))
{
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeGroup['attribute_group_id'];
    $model->setAttributeGroupId($attributeGroupId);
}   
    $model->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId);
}   





$model->addData($_attribute_data);
$model->setEntityTypeId(Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId());
$model->setIsUserDefined(1);



try {
    $model->save();

    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product',$code);
    $attributeId = $attribute->getId();
    assignAttributeToGroup($attributeId,$attributeGroupId,$attributeSetId);

} catch (Exception $e) { echo '<p>Sorry, error occured while trying to save the attribute. Error: '.$e->getMessage().'</p>'; }

 }
```

the above function is taken from this website.
I call this function on my script as following:

```
  createAttribute('test', 'Label Test', "multiselect", "simple",'77');
```

Now as you can see, all the attributes that i want to create for my magento store are multi-select dropdowns, so i add attribute values for the newly created attribute with the following function:

```
 function addAttributeValue($arg_attribute, $arg_value)
{
    $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');

    $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    if(!attributeValueExists($arg_attribute, $arg_value))
    {
        $value['option'] = array($arg_value,$arg_value);
        $result = array('value' => $value);
        $attribute->setData('option',$result);
        $attribute->save();
    }

    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;
    $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);

    foreach($options as $option)
    {
        if ($option['label'] == $arg_value)
        {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }


return false;
}
```

I have to do it this way because when i create the attribute, i do not know exactly what values will have

Both of the functions work perfectly, creates the attribute, it adds it in the correct attribute set, also correctly adds the attribute values that i want, but i face the following scenario:

I create a product, add it to the set  in which i added the newly created attribute with the above function, the attribute then appears in backend on the product edit page, but whenever i try to save something for it, it does not save. The page refreshes, the message from session is Product saved, but the attribute value selected is not there for that product. Practically, i can't save a value for this attribute from product backend edit page

I refresh all index management after my script runs, but the problem persists. Also i need to mention that i create this way about over 1000 attributes, with at least 4-5 values for each, so the amount of data is massive....so i need to make this to work programatically.
If anyone could give me a hint for why the above is not functioning correctly, i would really appreciate it.

Many thanks in advace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing specifically what's going wrong, I'm confident that your problems will be solved by using the class responsible for dealing with catalog EAV, namely, [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L35) - formerly known as `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup`. This class and its parent [`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php#L35) have everything necessary to CRUD attributes and any enumerated values.

```
$setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$setup->addAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'your_attr_code',
    array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'label' => 'Test'
    )
);
```

The nice thing about using this class is that it has a `_prepareValues()` method which sets default parameters specific for catalog entity attributes (ref `catalog_eav_attribute` table) as well as the parameters common to all EAV attributes (ref `eav_attribute` table & the parent `_prepareValues()` method).

Your best source for understanding **and examples** is to look at setup scripts in *Mage/Catalog/sql/* and *Mage/Catalog/data/*.